# Express NodeJS + ReactJS - My token storage Auth with the back

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm junior dev I'm rly struggling finding a way to do it, already went throught doc but my xp is not enough to completely understand it.

I'm sending a request to the API with somes parameters and it returns me a token, now I guess I have to send it to my front port 3000 in ReactJS and tell to react that if the user doesnt have the token then, he can't see the homepage. My goal is to make people log-in with an other account website from the API (OAuth2 Method).

I'm not asking you to do it for me , I just want some help regardless of what I should look for in internet

```
const env = require('dotenv').config();
console.log(env);
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// CORS setup
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    app.use(cors());
} else {
    app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
}
// Authorization
app.get('/authorize', (req, res) => {
    const client_id = process.env.API_KEY;
    const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/auth/callback';

    const authorizeUrl = `https://www.betaseries.com/authorize?client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}`;

    res.redirect(authorizeUrl);
});

//authO callblack
app.get('/auth/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const client_id = process.env.API_KEY;
    const client_secret = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
    const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/auth/callback';
    const code = req.query.code;

    try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.betaseries.com/oauth/access_token', {
            client_id,
            client_secret,
            redirect_uri,
            code
        });

        const access_token = response.data.access_token;
        res.send(`token: ${access_token}`);
        res.render()
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error.response.data);
        res.send(`error: ${error.message}`);
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
    }

});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server ON -> http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Thanks everyone for the help and reading
Sorry if I doubled posted or didnt completly understand how to ask help in stackoverflow